# Persisting data without a reference

Tags: c#

I have an a problem in C# where when I want to do a query to the database, I create a new instance of my `DBQuerier()` and call a `Run()` method on it.

The `DBQuerier` can connect to one of several databases, depending on what is passed to the run method - for example new `DBQuerier().Run(DBEnum.CatDatabase)`;

`DBQuerier` is part of a library as a variety of solutions use it.

I have a configuration file that I can load and parse to get all of the connections loaded into memory, used for the enum lookup. However, I am unsure of how to persist this information. It looks like a job for dependency injection:

`new DBQuerier(new MyConnectionStringLoader()).Run(...)`

However I don't want it to load the file and parse it every single time a db query is run in this way. I can't store it within DBQuerier because this object is created and discarded every time.

If I make a ConnectionStringManager class, if it is static then I can't cleanly dependency inject MyConnectionStringLoader into it, and it makes it harder to unit test. If I make it a singleton I have some similar issues.

Is there a good solution for this problem? Googling it has revealed myriad of posts saying 'never use static classes or singleton' so I am pretty stuck.

Comment: Never say never! I would say singleton and static are kind ok in that case. But why you don't create a class around DBQuerier which holds additional informations you need like ConnectionString?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `DbQuerier` does exactly the same for any database. The only thing changing is the connection string.

I would do something like this:

```
public interface IDbQuerier
{
    void Run();
}

public abstract class BaseDbQuerier : IDbQuerier
{
    private static IDictionary<DbEnum, string> _connections;

    static BaseDbQuerier()
    {
        _connections = // Load connection strings from configuration
    }

    protected abstract DbEnum Database { get; }

    public void Run()
    {
        string connectionString = _connections[Database];
        // DbQuerier logic
    }
}

public enum DbEnum
{
    CatDatabase,
    DogDatabase,
    TurtleDatabase
}
```

And then the different implementations:

```
public class CatDbQuerier : BaseDbQuerier
{
    protected override DbEnum Database { get { return DbEnum.CatDatabase; } }
}

public class DogDbQuerier : BaseDbQuerier
{
    protected override DbEnum Database { get { return DbEnum.DogDatabase; } }
}

public class TurtleDbQuerier : BaseDbQuerier
{
    protected override DbEnum Database { get { return DbEnum.TurtleDatabase; } }
}
```

Having different implementations for each database will let you to easily inject it to any class that needs it, using a DI framework of your choice.

Comment: That looks great, I'm going to try this approach. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation a singleton (which supports DI) is a valid route to go.

Comment: Googling patterns for this reveals a lot of sites saying singletons and DI bad... but I think you're right and I have to ignore them!

Comment: @SLC Opinions are like a particular *neither region* of the human body...everybody has one. As long as the interface makes sense, it is well documented and has a similar operational heuristic pattern as the rest of the system, it should be used.